AWS SSM StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost to a HTTPS VPC Endpoints
I have a VPC Endpoint with a private DNS allowing HTTPS connections (services.prod.abc.com)
I had a public bastion that allowed to open a socks5 connection
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bastion -D 9055 -C -q -N ec2-user@ec2-12-123-123-123.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Then I could query the endpoint locally using:
source ~/.aws/kp && curl -x socks5h://0:9055 --request POST \                             
  -H "Authorization: ${TOKEN_PROD}" \
  --url "https://services.prod.abc.com:9055/index" \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' 
  -d '{}'

Moving the bastion to a private subnet and configured SSM to create tunnel.
NOTE: The tunnel to my AURORA works and the code bellow allows me to connect to the DB on localhost:3308
aws ssm start-session --target ${BASTION_EC2_ID_PROD} \
--document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
--parameters '{"host":["rds-cluster-3-ap-southeast-2-prod.cluster-1111111111.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com"],"portNumber":["3306"],"localPortNumber":["3308"]}'

The problem comes when trying to connect to the VPC Endpoint that expect SSL on port 9055
source ~/.aws/kp && aws ssm start-session --target ${BASTION_ID_PROD} \
--document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
--parameters '{"host":["services.prod.abc.co"],"portNumber":["9055"],"localPortNumber":["9055"]}'

curl from my local with https://localhost:9055 like this one will freeze and handshake
curl -vvv --request POST \
  -H "Authorization: ${TOKEN_PROD}" \
  --location "https://localhost:9055/index" \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{}'

[::1]:9055...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9055
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [314 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [87 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0

curl from my local with http://localhost:9055 like this one will freeze
curl -vvv --request POST \
  -H "Authorization: ${TOKEN_PROD}" \
  --location "http://localhost:9055/index" \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{}'

[::1]:9055...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9055
> POST /index HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9055
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Authorization: Bearer abcabc
> accept: application/json
> content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 98
>
} [98 bytes data]
100    98    0     0  100    98      0      1  0:01:38  0:00:59  0:00:39 

How do I create a tunnel with my VPC Endpoint that accept HTTPS on port 9055 via my private bastion instance using SSM?
I tried the above and was able to have the connection accepted by SSM but was never able to retrieve the result from querying the endpoint service.
